# Use the ActionBarDrawerToggle for backstack as well

Tags: android

I am using the `DrawerLayout` to have a side menu and I set up the drawer fragment using the default:

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolBar)
```

I also have a `FrameLayout` inside the MainActivity(which hosts the drawer fragment).
And I transact fragments dynamically into this container.
What I want to do is to change the toolbar title and show a back button when there are any fragments in the container. Else show the usual hamburger icon which opens the drawer.

Is there a way I can use the same ActionBarDrawerToggle for back stack as well. Or is there a way I can use a toolbar inside each fragment which has a back button and title?

I tried using a toolbar in each fragment, but it does not quite look like the default action bar(of course be cause fragments are meant to have action bars).

I see Gmail app doing this with the ActionBarDrawerToggle itself(change it to back button when a new fragment comes up i.e when you open a mail). Can some one please point out how to do that.

CODE:

activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.xxx.yyy.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolBar);
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Fragment's setUp method:

```
/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 * @param toolBar
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolBar) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }
            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: I can understand your scenario but can you post some code so that we could suggest you changes according to your code..

Comment: @Droidwala I added the relevant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i generally do for above like scenario

**Step 1**
Make Toolbar part of your Main activity like below:[you have done it!]

```
<DrawerLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
      <Toolbar/>
      <FrameLayout/>
   </LinearLayout>
<NavigationView>
```

**Step 2**
While populating fragments inside main activity disable drawerindicator on ActionBarDrawerToggle like below:

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);   //disables hamburger icon
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content,frag)
                           .addToBackStack(null)
                           .commit();
```

**Step 3**
Change fragment's title inside Fragment life cycle methods like below:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance){
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
    ((ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity)getActivity).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Name of your fragment"); 
   }
```

**Step 4:**
You can handle back button click inside fragment class like below:

```
@Override
public void onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
 switch(item.getItemId()){
       case android.R.id.home://this will handle back navigation click
           getActivity().onBackPressed();
           break;
       }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Hope it helps!  Do comment below in case of any queries..

Comment: Will `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` make the Hamburger go away and show a back button? How do I handle this back button clicked?

Comment: yes,that will remove hamburger icon..back button click handling added to answer

Comment: Okay. I don't think setting title in `onActivityCreated` works when navigating back in the stack.

Comment: @Housefly sorry i did not get your above comment..can you explain that?

Comment: When you go back in the backstack of fragments, their `onActivityCreated` will not be called again, which means the action bar title will remain the title set in the last added fragment, instead of changing to what is currently on foreground.

Comment: [Fragment Lifecycle Diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)..hope it helps! :)